# Help deconstructing parts of 點唱機 - 按年份後，當年的流行曲就出來了，一按即點

Tags: translation

A Chinese family relative sent me this message (I am not Asian). I need some help deconstructing the message because at times the word sequence or implied idea is lost on me (even when I know most of the grammar rules). So, I have a series of related questions in this post that I hope will help me become a better student of Chinese language. Your patience is appreciated.

**The original message**

點唱機 (Diǎn chàngjī)

按年份後，當年的流行曲就出來了，一按即點

àn niánfèn hòu, dāngnián de liúxíng qǔ jiù chūláile, yī àn jí diǎn

http://thenostalgiamachine.com/index.html

Google Translate is not that good but delivers the following:

jukebox

By year after year of pop songs came out, a press that point

**My attempt at deconstructing the message with questions (in yellow)**

點唱機 (Diǎn chàngjī) -

> Ok, I get this idea as an electric singing machine but what happens when an idea (like this one - 點唱機) can belong to more than one thing? At least to one who has not heard this word before, could there be other interpretations? When I look at the words I thought of radio (not quite right, has news and talk), music-box (not quite, doesn't sing), etc. Jukebox was at the far-end of my list.

**按年份後，當年的流行曲就出來了，一按即點**

àn niánfèn hòu, dāngnián de liúxíng qǔ jiù chūláile, yī àn jí diǎn

> àn niánfèn hòu, dāngnián  - not sure how this one means "By year after year", I see fèn hòu but I don't follow the thread completely. I read àn nián 按年 as something to be contrasted with dāngnián 當年. Although again with (按年), I'm a bit lost on the implicit meaning. What comes to my mind is two ideas of "pushing down + year." In this case, I'd appreciate some help on this meaning?

Finally, although I can see that 的流行曲就出來了 refers to something popular (流行) came out (出來了),

> But I don't quite understand the notion of songs here. Could someone identify what I may be missing?

**EDIT:**

> I can see that my problems center around my not understanding some of the words such as  **點**, with a context of to order or request... I still can't find the proper meaning in a dictionary or translation program. Just wondering if the meaning is related to another word that changes it's default meaning?

[image: 點]

Comment: Regarding the edit, like other characters, you'd have to infer `點`'s meaning from its context. It's not a matter of "default" meanings changing. It's simply that none of the other meanings apply to "song/music (唱)" here.

Comment: A jukebox that lets one select a year; Once you request one, it plays the pop songs of the year. (simply) Click to select!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**按** (*verb*: press) **年份** (*noun*: year) **後** (after)

**當年** (*noun*: that year) **的** (*possessive particle*) **流行** (*adjective*: popular) **曲** (*noun*: song)<sup>*</sup> **就** (will) **出來** (*verb*: appear) **了** (*end of action particle*)

**一** (*adverb:* upon) **按** (*verb*: press) **即** (*adverb:* immediately) **點** (*verb:* select)

<sup>* note: 流行曲 (流行歌曲) means "pop songs".</sup>

---

Regarding `點唱機`, when you break it down the phrase becomes **點** (*verb:* order [as in ordering a drink at a bar]) **唱** (*noun:* music, song) **機** (*noun:* machine, device). From that, we can deduce it is a jukebox, since you normally can't *order* music on a radio or musicbox. It helps to know that radio is `收音機` and musicbox is `音樂盒`, but unfortunately there's no shortcuts around that.

Note that `唱` is far more commonly a verb.

Comment: 出來 implies the song playing, it's hiding the character in "(唱)出來" with "了". Nice deduction by the way!

Answer (score 1):

It *is* a little bit hard to understand. I try to translate it word by word, and hope it can help you.

> 點唱機

`點唱` means `request song`, so literally it means:

```
A machine, if you request a song to it, it will play it for you.
```

> 按年份後，當年的流行曲就出來了，一按即點

`按` here means `click`, `當年的流行曲` means `the popular song of the year`, so literally it means:

```
When you click the year (such as 1980), 
the popular songs of the year (such as 1980) will be played, 
click to request.
```

Comment: 先谢谢您， I see how 按 can mean click, now that you've mentioned it but I don't understand why 點 means request in this context. Hope you can help me understand this one. I also found that 曲子 means song but I am confused how to avoid 曲解 and the other possible meanings.

Comment: @TommieC. `點` has a meaning of `request`, `order`. Such as `點唱` means `request songs`, `點菜` means `order dishes`. Sorry I can't understand your question about `曲子`.